# Select listbox item internet explorer with VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, listbox

I'm developping a project in Excel 2013 with VBA. I have to select in a Internet Explorer a item in a listbox and go to another field. I tried many codes alreadt, but nothing works well. I found this way, but the listbox doesn't change the value.

```
Set kkk = .document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_ASPxCallbackPanel1_pc_EstipulanteEditar_ASPxRoundPanel2_cmb_SituacaoEdit_DDD_L_LBT").getElementsByClassName("dxeListBoxItem")

For Each el In kkk
    If el.innertext = "Ativo" Then
        el.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next el
```

I actually need to change the item on listbox, before to go to the next field.

Thank you

Comment: What does it do? Do you get any errors? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set kkk = .document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_ASPxCallbackPanel1_pc_EstipulanteEditar_ASPxRoundPanel2_cmb_SituacaoEdit_DDD_L_LBT").getElementsByClassName("dxeListBoxItem")

SetSelectByText(kkk, "Ativo")
```

Helper sub:

```
Sub SetSelectByText(sel, txt)
Dim l As Long, x As Long
    l = sel.Options.Length
    For x = 0 To l - 1
        If sel.Options(x).Text = txt Then
            sel.selectedIndex = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but i had a error in

sel.selectedIndex = x
object doesnt support this property or method